# What crossplatform libraries do you recommend for Haxe?

Tags: libraries, haxe

I have already investigated.
I found nme,neash...Physaxe  Do you know others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- format
- hscript
- utest
- haxealtdate
- hxJson2
- xpath
- ArrayTools/HashTools/IterTools/ListTools/StatTools

You can find all of them on the [haxelib page](http://lib.haxe.org/all).